# Can not get all the data from the link while using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am new to selenium and scraping data and trying to get all the data from the class name = rd-review in this below website, however the code returns none.

Is there any solution for it ?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
op.add_argument('--incognito')
op.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/MS CM/chromedriver.exe',options=op)
driver.get('https://www.real.de/product/325971045/?id_unit=382673369576')


elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('rd-review__stars')

for e in elem:
    print(e)
```

Here is the picture of the data I want to crawl :

[image: image description here]

Comment: What do u exactly wanna scrape? There is no text within the `svg` class.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. Past the code as text in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `selenium` to get the review data. It's all there via API.

```
import requests


reviews = "https://www.real.de/pdp-test/api/v1/325971045/product-reviews/?offset=0&limit=500"
data = requests.get(reviews).json()
print(f"Total reviews: {data['totalReviews']} | Average rating {data['averageRating']}")

for review in data['reviews']:
    print(f"{review['title']} - {review['rating']}")
```

Output:

```
Total reviews: 284 | Average rating 4.3
Sehr schlecht - 1
Hervorragende Qualität - 5
Preis und Qualität überzeugen - 5
Angeblich hochwertige Qualität  - 2
Schlafkomfort bestens - 5
Hält was es verspricht - 5
Bin begeistert - 5
Süße Träume - 5
Klasse! - 5
Nach 2 Minaten komplett durchgelegen - 1
Sehr schlechte Matratze  - 1
Top Produkt  - 5
Ausgezeichnet!!!!!! - 5
and so on...
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Can I ask you how I get the link for the reviews like this ? Is it possible if I i want to crawl not only reviews but also product descriptions and other data ?

Comment: Look into your Developer Tool of your favorite browser. Then go to Network and choose the XHR tab.

Comment: I followed what you wrote but there is nothing in XHR tab. Sorry. I am a newbie :(.

Comment: Open a new private window. Then, open the Developer Tool, select Network, and XHR. Finally, paste the link and watch the network traffic.

Comment: Oh Thank you. I found link now.
However, can I use the link above to crawl as many time as I want ? Because in the past, I had been blocked the ip by the website once? ( not this website but another website)

Comment: An API should handle a bit more than plain website scraping, but if you abuse it you might get throttled and/or banned, at least temporarily. Just go easy first and see how things go.

Comment: hi, baduker, i ask a new question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64672385/why-for-loop-only-returns-the-last-result-repeatedly . Would you please take a look at it and answer it for me ? that would be a big help for me. thanks